# DRF Update Existing Objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF and python so go easy on me... I can successfully get the RoadSegment objects, but I cannot figure out how to update an existing object

I have the following model:

```
class RoadSegment(models.Model):
   location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   entryline = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
   trafficstate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

With the following serializer:

```
class RoadSegmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RoadSegment
        fields = ('entryline','trafficstate','location')
```

And the following view

```
class RoadSegmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RoadSegment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RoadSegmentSerializer
```

My urls.py looks as follows:

```
router.register(r'roadsegment', RoadSegmentViewSet, base_name='roadsegment-detail')
```

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/roadsegment/ returns

```
[{"entryline":"2nd","trafficstate":"main","location":"downtown"},{"entryline":"3nd","trafficstate":"low","location":"downtown"}]
```

I would like to be able to update an existing object

PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/roadsegment/

```
{"entryline":"2nd","trafficstate":"SOMENEWVALUE","location":"downtown"}
```

Comment: I don't see any sights how your items are identified. Usually ID is pointed in resource URL, i.e. ```/api/v1/roadsegment/42/```.

Comment: Did you take a look into official tutorial? Here is an example which is pretty similar with your case: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, you need to provide the following:

```
lookup_field -> Most probably the ID of the record you want to update 
lookup_url_kwarg -> The kwarg in url you want to compare to id of object
```

You need to define a new url in your `urls.py` file. This will carry the `lookup_url_kwarg`. This can be done as follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^your_url/$', RoadSegmentViewSet.as_view()),
    url(r'^your_url/(?P<kwarg_name_of_your_choice>\w+)/$',RoadSegmentViewSet.as_view()),
)
```

`kwarg_name_of_your_choice` needs to placed in your viewset as `lookup_url_kwarg`.

The request that now you would be sending is:

PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/roadsegment/object_id_to_update/

And you are done.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it working with this information.  For some reason, the url must be in urlpatterns, not the router.